# How to remove varbinary data from Sql server data base?

Tags: sql-server, database, varbinary, dml

I have table with a `varbinary(max)` column declared like that:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Documents] (
     [row_id]            DECIMAL (10)    IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
     [contents]         VARBINARY (MAX) NULL
     -- Document metadata columns here
     . . .
```

The column `contents` has the contents of binary files, but now this binary data is migrated to an external backend provider so I need to remove the contents of this column for all rows in order to free space on server disk.

Since we have a few remaing disc space I need to do it the best efficient way. I'm looking to `.WRITE` clause that it seems it does not log (or log less information) to database but this is not mandatory.

So how can delete this binary data from column `contents` using sql server sentence?

Comment: Anything you do here will be fully logged. It is required to maintain ACID. What you may have to do with limited log space is update in batches.

Comment: Thank you @SeanLange. Any `sentence` to delete this binary data?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I prefer not delete the column just in case.

Comment: `update documents set contents = null`?

Comment: What is the point of keeping the column "just in case" when you want to delete the data ?

Comment: will sql reclaim space back when we update data from varbinary to null?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm not sure If I can have any other query or stored procedure that access this column.

Comment: Shouldn't you find out? Otherwise other code may still store data there or worse, read bad (empty) data when a value *is* available. In fact, dropping the column and finding what breaks is *safer* than allowing broken code to run undetected